# Is Excel-driven testing possible through selenium?

Tags: excel, testing, selenium, testng, drive

Sahi allowed me to enter the desired functions into a spreadsheet and then it would run those functions. Different combinations would result in different scenarios.Can i do something similar using selenium? I want to pick and call tests/scripts/functions through an excel file. I am currently using the testng framework to get data from excel files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following blog for a relative answer on using data provider using TestNG for Selenium.

http://blog.varunin.com/2011/10/data-driven-testing-using-junit-and.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support. [Spock framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) has an excellent support for data-driven tests. A combination of [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory), Spock and Selenium2/WebDriver can provide you more than what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use a framework such as POI to read your Excel spreadsheet and return these values in a @DataProvider.

Comment: +1 Exactly, @DataProvider annotation is used to implement data driven testing in selenium RC. We need to add reference to jxl jar library to read from excel sheet